# What's the interfaceID for ERC-20?

Tags: erc-20, ether, interfaces

What's the interfaceID for ERC-20? It's not in the EIP. It's shown for 165 and 721 but not for ERC-20.

Answer (score 5):

Short Answer probably `0x36372b07`

I think you can add the interfaces like this in your ERC20 Contract constructor, you need to import IERC20 and ERC20 and ERC165 (or ERC165Storage) from OpenZeppelin

```
_registerInterface(type(IERC20).interfaceId);
_registerInterface(ERC20.name.selector);
_registerInterface(ERC20.symbol.selector);
_registerInterface(ERC20.decimals.selector);
```

and test them like this

```
const erc165Interface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x01ffc9a7'); // true
const tokenInterface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x36372b07'); // true
const tokenNameInterface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x06fdde03'); // true
const tokenSymbolInterface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x95d89b41'); // true
const tokenDecimalsInterface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x313ce567'); // true
const tokenNoneExistingInterface = await mytokenInstance.supportsInterface('0x19be5360'); // false
```

here is also a link
https://github.com/ticket721/erc2280#erc-165-supported-interfaces

Answer (score 2):

Solidity has `type` function:

```
function interfaceId() public pure returns(bytes4){
    return type(IERC20).interfaceId;
}
```

with this function, you can get the `interfaceId` of any interface

Comment: How does that answer the question ?

Comment: result of return will be the answer. i show how to fish

Comment: You should also explain how to fish while showing it. A little explanation does not hurt.

Comment: @Itération122442 Agree.

Answer (score -1):

Found this example in a contract.

```
/**
* @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}
*/
function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
       return
           interfaceId == type(IERC721).interfaceId ||
           interfaceId == type(IERC721Metadata).interfaceId ||
           super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP is asking about the interface ID of ERC-20, not ERC-721.